# Mail App rules and iOS/iCloud clients

Tags: mail.app, mail-rules

Suppose I configure a rule in the MacOS desktop mail App that puts messages from one sender into a special folder.  I observe that this rule does not sync with the iCloud mail rules (which are also more limited), and I see that there are no rules at all supported in iOS.  Therefore I assume that if my desktop computer is asleep the rule will have no effect on how an arriving message is treated.

What happens when I wake my desktop computer up?  Will a previously-received message then be moved into the designated folder, with the same change now visible in the iOS and iCloud mail clients?

Similarly, what happens if the message arrives while my desktop computer is awake?  Will the message be immediately into the designated folder, with the change immediately visible in the iOS and iCloud clients?

Comment: What testing have you already done? This seems quite simple to check.

Comment: I am hoping that somebody will provide a clearer description of how all this fits together than my muddled brain has been able to synthesize.  And also, by asking the question as clearly as I can, I'm hoping to create something searchable on the web for others, since I didn't find such a thing when I looked.